# Relationship with Date table with multiple fields

Tags: powerbi, relationship, dax

I need to link Dates Tables with multiple fields from different tables that also must be linked between each other.

3 data sources:

- Milestones (has Project ID - unique values)
- Report - Benefits (linked with Milestones by Project ID - duplicates)
- Approved Savings (linked with Milestones by Project ID 0 duplicates)

Dates Table to be linked to:

Milestone table ( by "Close DATE" field)
Approved Savings ( by "Approval Date" field)

In addition, Milestones table also has another Date field which I also need to link later on. However, I cannot link Dates Table with more than 1 field.

[image]

Comment: The error is saying that you are creating 'ambiguity', you will not solve it in an easy way. You need to build a 'lead' table.

Comment: Thank you, PV8. Could you expand a bit on would you mean by "lead" table?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot slice on a column in a table from two sources that are related. Relationships are designed to be lazy, so when you take a value out of the 'One' side of the relationship, the 'Many' side of the relationship just follows.

`User removed May from our 'One' Date table on the column Month, so let's remove all May dates from our 'Many' Approved Savings table.`

Another acceptable use of relationships is introducing a second relationship to the same 'Many' column on the Approved Savings table, but from a different 'One' table. ( in this case, Milestones )

`User removed May from our 'One' Date table on the column Month, so let's remove all May dates from our 'Many' Approved Savings table. User also chose Mile Stone 445 from the 'One' Milestones table, so let's remove everything but May 2nd from the Date Column on the 'Many' Approved Savings table.`

Alternatively

`User removed June from our 'One' Date table on the column Month, so let's remove all June dates from our 'Many' Approved Savings table. User also chose Mile Stone 999 from the 'One' Milestones table, so let's remove everything but December 29th from the Date Column on the 'Many' Approved Savings table.`

In the second case, Obviously the Approved Savings table would be filtered to no rows, but it is still a valid configuration. After all, you told it to filter that way, so it's only doing it's job.

However, in your case you've introduced 'ambiguity' when the PowerBI Engine goes to interpret your relationships.

`User removed June from our 'One' date table on the column Month, so let's remove all June dates from our 'Many' Approved Savings table AND our 'Many' Milestones table . User also chose Mile Stone 999 from the 'One' Milestones but it doesn't exist because of the Previous relationship.`

Alternatively

`The 'One' date table attempts to filter both Milestones and Approved Savings. Date table is sliced to contain set X of dates. Milestones translates that set of X dates in to set of Y Milestones records. Now Approved Savings has Milestones attempting to filter with set Y and the Date table attempting to filter with set X. These are potentially conflicting sets of dates and PowerBI doesn't know which set is valid.`

If you removed the Date Table -> Approved Savings relationship, you would see two things:

- You could now set the Date Table -> Milestone relationship to active
- You would only me able to set an inactive relationship for Date Table -> Approved Savings ( assuming that you activated the Date Table -> Milestone relationship )

In any case, inactive relationships can still be triggered by utilizing [USERELATIONSHIP](https://dax.guide/userelationship/) in your measures. I would caution against using it, IMO its use is indicative of a troublesome or *potentially* poorly designed data model.

Comment: thank you for your reply. If USERELATIONSHIP is used in a poor data model. What would be a good data model in my case? Should I duplicate Approved Savings table (withing linking it to Milestones) and link it with Dates table while keeping Original Approved Savings table linked to Milestones?